# Write data on a custom folder with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write data on the device. But I don't want them to be public to the user and want to save them in a custom reposity. I tried this code

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("test/mytest")
print(fileURL)
try data?.write(to: fileURL)
```

this is the obtained path

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34567-234567dfgh-dfghj/Documents/test/mytest
```

But I get an error telling me that `mytest` could not be found in folder `test`

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the directory first before you call `write`:

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL)
var isDir: ObjCBool = ObjCBool(false)
let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL, isDirectory: &isDir)
if !exists && !isDir.boolValue {
    try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at url: fileURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
}
```

Although when you call `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`, you passed `true` to `create:`, the directory `/test/mytest` is **not created** because you **appended** it. So, you have to create it.

Comment: This means that with this solution the directory will be re-created each time I want to write a new file, so old files will be destroyed?

Comment: You create a directory only if the said directory does not exist. You can check if directory exists using FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fullPath, isDirectory:&isDir)

Comment: @user567 added a check

Comment: The code in this answer is wrong. This code only attempts to create the directory if it already exists and if it is already a directory.